# How to derive total number of items from a pagination endpoint?

Tags: javascript, pagination

I have an endpoint that returns a list of objects -- let's say that it's called `/getDogs`. The API provider exposes some basic pagination options (namely `offset` and `size`), but there's no way to get the total number of `dogs`.

I *could* do something like:
(pseudocode)

```
PAGE_SIZE
curPage = 0
while (items left in list)
  dogs = fetch('/getDogs', { offset: currentOffset, size: PAGE_SIZE })
  if dogs.length < PAGE_SIZE
    // we've found the last page
    return curPage * PAGE_SIZE + (PAGE_SIZE - dogs.length) // or something like this
  else
    curPage++
    currentOffset += PAGE_SIZE
```

This seems inefficient, which is a concern because the API is heavily rate-limited.

How can I efficiently derive the total number of objects using only the `offset` and `size`?

*Note: I'm trying to get the total number of objects so that I'll be able to A) display the number of total pages and let the user navigate to it, and B) reverse the display order of the items (the endpoint returns the items in an illogical order -- least-recently updated *first*)*

Comment: And you are confident that it doesn't return a total number of records field? That seems odd that is would provide offset and size without also providing the total number available.

Comment: What API are you using?

Comment: http://developers.marketo.com/rest-api/assets/smart-lists/

Comment: @imvain2 Yeah, it doesn't return the total records. The API is fairly poorly-designed :(